# No widget drag/drop in Qt Creator after Blender-startup

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, blender, qt-creator

My problem is that every time I start Blender 2.63 in 12.04 (64-bit), I am not able to drag and drop widgets in Qt Creator anymore, even after closing Blender again.

I have tried restarting Qt, Compiz and Unity (at least I think I did by executing `compiz --replace` and `unity`; I'm quite new to Linux) with no effect. After logging out and back in, everything is back to normal.

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Qt Creator is version 2.4.1 with Qt 2.8

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer, but I can confirm this bug. There are other applications, where drag and drop no longer works once blender was started (Clementing, Kmail). I suppose blender does something it shouldn't do, but the other applications are at fault too. They should not get that easily confused by a misbehaving program.

The only workaround I know is to log out and back in.